# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') (tried many solutions already)

Tags: null, typeerror, addeventlistener

I understand this issue, and most solutions, however i cannot seem to resolve this in a small application test.

I've tried; wrapping in a DOMContentLoaded, defer script is at the bottom of HTML body, tried the IF statement approach. I dont get why its still getting to the listener before the DOM element is built.

Testing on a local node v14 server, can't imagine that would be an issue.

Any possible solutions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Compositor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="image-input" name="images" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple required>
    <div id="preview"></div>
    <button id="process-button" disabled>Process Images</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.13.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const input = document.getElementById('image-input');
    const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
    const processButton = document.getElementById('process-button');
    const result = document.getElementById('result');

    let imageUrls = [];

    input.addEventListener('change', function () {
        const formData = new FormData();
        Array.from(input.files).forEach((file, index) => {
            formData.append(`images`, file);
        });

        fetch('/upload', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                imageUrls = data.urls;
                preview.innerHTML = '';
                imageUrls.forEach(url => {
                    const img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = url;
                    img.dataset.id = url;
                    preview.appendChild(img);
                });
                Sortable.create(preview);
                processButton.disabled = false;
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });

    processButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const order = Array.from(preview.children).map(img => imageUrls.indexOf(img.dataset.id));
        fetch('/process', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({ order }) })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                result.innerHTML = '';
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = data.url;
                result.appendChild(img);
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = data.url;
                link.download = 'composite.png';
                link.textContent = 'Download image';
                result.appendChild(link);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
});
```

Error:

```
script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:6:7
```

Thanks
David

Expectation for the error not to exist :)

```
script.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:6:7
```